# What is the best Way to modify PDF in Django?

Tags: django, pdf, pypdf

Actually I want to modify PDF which is Certificate need to change name, date, course name and course description. I have tried the pypdf2 but doesn't work for me. The "change name" data doesn't modify.

Here is What i tried so far

```
        
   

pdfFileObj = open('/home/nawaf/Documents/5_dec_truck_courses/29_Nov_Updated/truck_courses/LMS_Online_App/static/certificate.pdf', 'rb')

   pdf_reader = PdfFileReader(io.BytesIO(pdfFileObj.read()))
   pdf_page = pdf_reader.pages[0]
   pdf_text = pdf_page.extractText()

   change_name = pdf_text.replace("John Doe", "Nawaf").replace("NAME OF THE 
   COURSETO","Rent Everything").replace("The course description will go her.","My Own 
   Description")
   pdfFileObj.close()

pdf_writer = PdfFileWriter(pdfFileObj)
with open('/home/nawaf/Documents/5_dec_truck_courses/29_Nov_Updated/truck_courses/test/test.pdf', 'wb') as f:
      pdf_writer.addPage(page=pdf_page)
      pdf_writer.add_annotation(page_number=0, annotation=pdf_reader.metadata)
      pdf_writer.write(f)
      f.close()
```

Comment: _I have tried the pypdf2 but doesn't work for me._ -> What doesn't work? Do you get any exceptions? Not the expected result? Please [edit] your question and be more specific.

Comment: I'm actually asking for the better solution ? In the above code I was unable to write the replaced data in the new file.